# Contact us as you find convenient

Tags: meaning-in-context

The context is that clients can use means of communication convenient to them.
One employee at my work proposed the phrasing below.

> Contact us as you find convenient.

Does that sentence make sense to you? I wanted to put it in other way, taking into account the context:

> Contact us in any way convenient to you.

I think the first phrasing means that the clients can contact us at any time convenient to them. The first phrasing is absolutely incorrect in this context. Am I right?

I want to know whether the first sentence has exactly the same meaning as the second one? I mean the way of communication , not the time convenient to someone.

Comment: Is the sentence necessary?

Comment: If you are in a sales context, people will contact you as it is convenient to them whether or not you say it.  If you explicitly need to get a reply from them, then you want to explicitly spell out the means to contact you.  Otherwise, if I'm 103, and my preferred contact method is telegraph, how would I go about getting a hold of you?

Comment: @Ian MacDonald It seems to me that you understand what i mean, based on your previous comments that were deleted. Is the first sentence totally wrong in the context of means of communication?

Comment: @Amandedouce, I think you are right that the first sentence would be taken to mean "at a time you find convenient" rather than "via a method you find convenient".

Answer (score 1):

The original is simply not idiomatic. I'd expect:

*Please contact us at your [earliest] convenience.*

Google Books [will show you that](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22at%20your%20earliest%20convenience%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22contact%20us%20at%20your%20earliest%20convenience%22).

[Edit]
For the manner, I'd suggest a better formulation would be:

*Contact us in the manner most convenient to you.*

Comment: Oh god! Why do you all keep writing this?

Comment: @Amandedouce, because your question's detail is easily overlooked.  :-)

Comment: Marius, the OP is asking for an expression regarding the MEANS of communication, not the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at various websites and marketing brochures, they simply provide whatever means of contact they prefer (post, phone, email, web form) and leave it to you to decide how you want to contact them. Provide the necessary information, extend the invitation ("Contact us!"), and leave it to the other person to choose the method.